# Can the word 'design' be used as a metaphor 'intentional'?

Tags: word-meaning, word-play

Is my statement below, referring to the artist's adage, used correctly if I use them metaphorically as opposites with 'default' meaning 'unwittingly' and 'decision' as 'intentional'?

Whether by decision or default, Van Gogh's statement, "If you hear a voice within you say 'you can't paint', then by ALL MEANS paint, and that voice will be silenced",I was immediately struck by the apropos double entendre.

Comment: Very well written, but no double meaning shows. Also, the double entendre needs some spice or it's just a pun.

Comment: Are you assuming some spurious connection between ***design*** in your title, and ***decision / decide*** in the question text?

Comment: Doing something "[by design](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/by-design)" means doing it intentionally but I've no idea what your question means.

Answer (score 1):

If you're hoping that what you wrote sounds natural, I'd have to say no, it doesn't.

It is so unnatural-sounding as to be unclear, and I can't really tell if you're trying to imply 'intention' on the part of you, the reader, or Van Gogh himself. Either way, nobody makes a 'decision' - a personal, conscious choice - to *notice* a double-meaning. If it's a choice, then you must be aware of both options. It just doesn't make sense. Likewise, a speaker either intends a double-meaning or they don't.

You would be better simply saying "*Whether intentional or not...*". It's a pretty straightforward thing to say; it doesn't really need a metaphor.

Just one more thing - do you really mean to say there is a "*double entendre*" in the quotation? This refers to a double-meaning, and typically implies that the second meaning is sexually suggestive. I don't see anything like this in this quotation. I'm only guessing, but I think you are trying to suggest that there is *irony* in it - perhaps because he was speaking about a metaphorical inner-voice talking to him, when it is now understood Van Gogh suffered from bipolar disorder which can mean one actually hears voices. This would be a typical example of real-life 'dramatic irony', where the reader knows something that the speaker does not (Van Gogh likely did not understand his own mental illness as bipolar disorder was not recognised until 1851).

Answer (score 0):

I have upvoted Astralbee's answer because I believe he has deciphered what you want to say.

But I must add that what you wrote is not just unnatural in the sense of "odd." It is unnatural in the sense of not even being grammatical.

> Whether ... Van Gogh's statement

is a sentence fragment. It has a subject, namely "Van Gogh's statement," but no verb is applied to the subject.

The grammatical problem is that what you really want to say concerns a perception of yours about the statement. You do not get to that until:

> I was immediately struck ...

That sentence is valid grammatically but confusing becasue, as astralbee pointed out, the phrase "double entendre" is not precisely what you mean. Nor is the contrast between "design" and "default" exactly on target because a default can be part of an intentional design. The precise meaning that you want is whether the "voices" were intended literally or figuratively (a distinction that sloppy popular usage has almost obliterated).

I am not so certain that expressing what astralbee believes is your thought is easy because it is subtle. Here is an attempt (taking advantage of astralbee's mention of irony):

When reading Van Gogh's adage of " ...  ," I was immediately struck by the ironic ambiguity of whether he intended "literal voices" or "figurative voices."

I hope this helps. The thought is one worth elucidating clearly.